# How can I tell the exact time when a drive disconnected?

Tags: macos, usb, logs

I have a USB drive (a Drobo) that appears disconnecting randomly after 10-20 hours. I'm trying to gather data to help understand the root cause of the problem so I'd like to understand the timing of the disconnection. Is there a log file that would have this kind of data ? On a related note, is there a log that would have generally relevant data that I could use to try to correlate to the disconnections?